# Substrate pallet does not compile with tag devhub/latest

Tags: substrate

I've been using substrate-node-template of tag="monthly-2021-05" for a while, but decided to switch everything to the tag="devhub/latest". Now my pallet fails to compile with the folowing errors:

```
error[E0277]: the trait bound `AuthorizedAccount<T, VendorPermission>: TypeInfo` is not satisfied
   --> pallets/aipallet/src/lib.rs:53:1
    |
53  | #[frame_support::pallet]
    | ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ the trait `TypeInfo` is not implemented for`MyStruct
```

This error is repeated for all my structs and enums. It seems to be something simple and I tried to few things like adding TypeInfo into derive part of struct declaration or adding/removing scale_info into Cargo.toml etc, but no luck. Please help

Answer (score 2):

Fixed by adding TypeInfo to each struct and enum declaration derive list plus adding to Config trait declaration

```
+ scale_info::TypeInfo
```